# Check if PDF has been exported from Word/Google Docs

Tags: pdf, ms-word, ocr, export-to-pdf

I'm doing some work with OCRing PDFs, and I'm curious if there is a way to check if a PDF has been exported from Word (or Google Docs).  I can check if the PDF has been OCR'd with Xpdf's pdffonts.  I know Word and Google Docs automatically OCR the exported PDFs, so if I find that the PDF hasn't been OCR'd. I know it hasn't been exported.  But if it has been OCR'd, is there any way to check if the PDF was exported from Word/Google Docs VS simply OCRd with a program like Tesseract?  Specifically I'm working in JavaScript but any information is useful.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking this up, what I am doing now is using pdfinfo (from Xpdf) with the -meta flag to check if the PDF has XMP metadata.  PDFs exported from Word and Google Docs do not have this metadata, but other PDFs do.